# PowerApps: Loading a form and gallery from an email with a deep link - Want only to load specific ID in both

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

Can anyone tell me why this piece of code is loading the newest item (I do not want this) and the correct ID item (this is what I want to load) into my gallery. And maybe how do I get it to stop loading the newest item?

This is only happening when I click on the deep link in the email produced by PowerApps. Not when I load the app and click on an item from my dashboard gallery to load.

How I am understanding the code to read is: filter this gallery with lead_history information where the LeadID column equals the selected id from Gallery_Dashboard OR where the LeadID column equals the parameter passed in the URL called ID.

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        Lead_History,
        Or(
        LeadID = Gallery_Dashboard.Selected.ID,
        LeadID = Value(Param("ID")))
    ),
    "HistoryDate",
    SortOrder.Descending
)
```

**More details:**

**App onStart:**

```
If(!IsBlank(Param("ID")), Set(varRecordToOpen,First(Filter(Lead_Data,ID=Value(Param("ID"))))));
```

**Timer on the screen that first loads:**

Duration:

```
600
```

OnTimerEnd:

```
If(!IsBlank(Param("ID")),Navigate(Edit, Cover,{LoadLead:LookUp(Lead_Data, ID = Value(Param("ID"))), LoadHistory:LookUp(Lead_History, LeadID = Value(Param("ID")))}));
```

**Edit Screen**

Edit Form - Item:

```
varRecordToOpen
```

Gallery - Items:

```
    Filter(
        Lead_History,
        Or(
        LeadID = Gallery_Dashboard.Selected.ID,
        LeadID = Value(Param("ID")))
    ),
    "HistoryDate",
    SortOrder.Descending
)
```

I think this is all the code that I am using to make this deep link work.

Comment: Try changing the parameter name from ID to anything else.. I.e. ItemId. This sounds funny but I had same issue and just changing the parameter name worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you have no condition in your `OR` statement. So what makes the app choose between `LeadID = Gallery_Dashboard.Selected.ID OR LeadID = Value(Param("ID")`?

I think that is the problem here.